# Telerik ASP.Net Chart Control doesnt render properly if its placed on a SharePoint Modal Dialog Box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, modal-dialog, telerik-charting

I have developed a Chart Webpart which uses Telerik ASP.Net Chart Control. When a user clicks on the chart, I have placed a script which opens another Modal Dialog box with the same Chart Control but with bigger width and height. This works perfectly when the Chart control is added on a Webpart Page.

```
function ChartClick() 
{
    var ev = arguments[0] || window.event,
    selectedChart = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
    OpenDialog(selectedChart, true);   
}
```

But if I place this Webpart on a pop-up page and then click on the chart, the modal dialog box opens but the Chart is not rendered properly. It appears distorted completely.

Has anyone come acroos this problem? Any help would be considered as a gift!

Cheers!